# Supercsv - unable to find method exception

Tags: java, parsing, csv, supercsv

I have the below implementation.

```
csvReader = new CsvBeanReader(new InputStreamReader(stream), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
lastReadIdentity =  (T) csvReader.read(Packages.class, Packages.COLS);
```

In my Packages.class

I have set my unitcount variable.

```
public String getUnitCount() {
    return unitCount;
}
public void setUnitCount(String unitCount) {
    this.unitCount = unitCount;
}
```

This works fine when it is taken as a string, but when taken as a integer, it throws the below exception. Please help

```
private int unitCount;
public int getUnitCount() {
    return unitCount;
}
public void setUnitCount(int unitCount) {
    this.unitCount = unitCount;
}
```

Exception:

```
org.supercsv.exception.SuperCsvReflectionException: unable to find method setUnitCount(java.lang.String) in class com.directv.sms.data.SubscriberPackages - check that the corresponding nameMapping element matches the field name in the bean, and the cell processor returns a type compatible with the field
context=null
at org.supercsv.util.ReflectionUtils.findSetter(ReflectionUtils.java:139)
at org.supercsv.util.MethodCache.getSetMethod(MethodCache.java:95)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about SuperCsv, but [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) should be able to handle this without a hitch, not to mention it is at least 3 times faster to parse your input.

Just annotate your class:

```
public class SubscriberPackages {

    @Parsed(defaultNullRead = "0") // if the file contains nulls, then they will be converted to 0.
    private int unitCount;   // The attribute name will be matched against the column header in the file automatically.
}
```

To parse the CSV into beans:

```
// BeanListProcessor converts each parsed row to an instance of a given class, then stores each instance into a list.
BeanListProcessor<SubscriberPackages> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<SubscriberPackages>(SubscriberPackages.class);

CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial.
parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor); //uses the bean processor to handle your input rows
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); // extracts header names from the input file.

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings); //creates a parser with your settings.
parser.parse(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/file.csv"))); //all rows parsed here go straight to the bean processor

// The BeanListProcessor provides a list of objects extracted from the input.
List<SubscriberPackages> beans = rowProcessor.getBeans();
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: I'm using univocity-parsers-1.5.6 and I'm finding difficulty in escaping the last line while reading/parsing a file. Can you please help how can I ignore/escape last line while reading/parsing a file ?

Comment: How about just ignoring the last parsed row?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I removed the last row from the list after checking its content. 

But I was looking for any better method like skipping 'n' lines from start / end. Or if comment can be used and its datatype can be changed from char to string so that it can accommodate a character as well as string.

Comment: Add '#' to the start of the line and it will be ignored. You can't skip lines from the end as the end can only be known when you parsed everything.

Comment: Actually..I don't have control over writing the files